# Developing a chess game in java, my board object is not getting modified properly

Tags: java, object, scope, chess

so I am fairly new to the Java language, so there must be something here that I am forgetting. So for a homework I have to create a chess game in Java. As of now, I have created a class for a "Pawn" piece, and another class called "GameState", which contains the board for the game. The Pawn class has a method called move() which takes the x and y coordinates of the spot on the board to move to, as well as the current gamestate object, and the move() function will move the pawn to that spot on the board. The pawn class is extended from an abstract class called "Piece", and all the other specific piece classes I make will inherit from this class.

My problem is that the move() method is not properly modifying the board in the GameState class.

Below is the relevant snippet of code from the move() method of the pawn class:

```
public GameState move(GameState state, int xDest, int yDest) {
    //Make sure that the destination coordinates are not outside of the board
    if (xDest < 0 || yDest < 0 || xDest >= state.getBoardCols() || yDest >= state.getBoardRows()) 
        return null;        

    /*
     * A black piece moves forward on the downward pointing y
     * axis, and a a white piece moves up. Thus, we assign a
     * +1 to the variable if the piece is white, and -1 if the
     * piece is black. 
     */
    int dir = (color.equals("black")) ? -1 : 1;

    //In the case that the pawn is moving forward 2 spaces
    if (firstMove == true && xCurr == xDest && yDest == yCurr + dir * 2) {
        if (state.insertPiece(xDest, yDest, this)) {
            firstMove = false;

            //Null the old coordinates the Pawn was at
            state.nullCoordinates(xCurr, yCurr);                
            return state;
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

so, the insertPiece() method is what actually inserts the pawn at the x and y coordinates on the board. I used the eclipse debugger, and when the program is running the insertPiece() method, the board of the "state" object does indeed insert the pawn at the correct x and y coordinates. Now, I have a unit test function which is running this move method, shown here:

```
state = pawnToTest.move(state, 4, 1 + dir * 2);
assertEquals(false, pawnToTest.firstMove());
assertEquals(pawnToTest, state.getPiece(4, 1 + dir * 2));
assertEquals(null, state.getPiece(4, 1));
```

Now, in this scenario, I have a pawn placed at x=4,y=1 on the board initially (which indexes to [1][4], but whatever). So, the first move() call here will move it forward to x=4,y=3. Now, I've verified w/ the debugger that INSIDE the pawnToTest.move() call, the board at x=4,y=3 does indeed contain the pawn. However, when the program exits the control of that method, the pawn is no longer at that location, and so the 2nd assert equals fails. Why is the board not getting modified properly?

EDIT: nvm, I foudn the bug, turns out I was not updating the position of the pawn properly, stupid me :P

Comment: Can you show us your `insert()` function? It sounds like your `Pawn` instance isn't being updated.

Comment: Nevermind I found the bug, turns out the pawn's x and y coordinates were being updated prematurely, thanks though!

Comment: @Kamal you may want to consider making your game state object immutable.